# Monitoring folder external changes

Tags: android, ftp, monitoring

I'm a bit newbie with Android and I have a problem. I have an FTP server in my android device which receives a file that I must read and store in my sqllite DB inside my android.

I want to monitor that folder so I can take that file when it's created.

I must monitor that folder with another app that I'm developing so I think that FileObserver is useless, the reason is according to android documentation FileObserver ---> "fire an event after files are accessed or changed by any process on the device".

The process that writes in my ftpFolder is outside in another device with another OS.

What must I use? I was thinking about BroadcastReceiver? But I don't know how.

Thank you very much to everybody.

EDIT:Sorry I didn't explain correctly. My ftp server, that is an app in my android device, has a home folder called /ftpHome in my external storage. Another device with another OS (THEOS) is sending some files to that folder. How can I scan it from my android app? Thank you very much

Comment: `I want to monitor that folder`. Which folder? You did not talk about a folder before. `The process that writes in my ftpFolder is outside in another device with another OS`. ?? Please elaborate. ``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it. As I told you I'm a bit newbie and I completely forgot to put in my manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Thank you for everything.

P.S: Finally I'm using a service with a fileobserver that notifies me when something happen in that folder.